# Adding two numbers through recursion C++

Tags: c++, recursion

```
#include <iostream>

int sum(int a, int b) {
  if (b != 1) {
    sum(a, b - 1);   
  }
  a = a + 1;
  return a;   
}

int main() {
  int a = sum(10, 12);
  std::cout << a;    
}
```

Basically I am adding two numbers through recursion, so I am recursively calling function by decreasing number `b` and incrementing number `a` that much times, but result I get is `11`.

Comment: recursion does not only require to call the function but also to actually use the result of that call

Comment: You aren't using the result of your recursive sum call

Comment: What response are you expecting here?  22?

Comment: Yeah i was expecting the result 22, but i was not even using the result of recursive calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me rewrite your code just a bit to make the mistake more obvious:

```
int partial_result(int a,int b) { /*....*/ }

int sum(int a, int b) {

    if(b != 1){
        partial_result(a, b-1);
    }
    a = a+1;
    return a;
}
```

Calling the `partial_result` has no influence on what `sum` returns and `sum` is the same as

```
int sum(int a,int b) {
    return a+1;
}
```

For the recursion you have to actually use the result of the recursive calls:

```
int sum(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 1) {
        return a+1;
    } else {
        return sum(a,b-1) + 1;
    }
}
```

...or more similar to your code:

```
int sum(int a, int b) {
    if (b != 1) {
        a = sum(a,b-1);
    }
    return a+1;
}
```

Note that recursion will not stop when `b` is negative. Even if you only ever want to call the function with positives values, it is better to change the condition to `if (b <= 2)`. This will return wrong results for negatives but at least it will return something.

Comment: Just as a remark: if `b` is negative, the recursions won't terminate.

Comment: @StefanKssmr true, didn't mention it because OPs code makes the same assumption. Will add a note

Answer (score 1):

Evalute the return value of the recursivly called function `a = sum(a, b - 1);`. Additonally, make sure that no value less than 1 is entered as b with this implementation. A call with b=0 will also fail.